# returning courses from times

Tags: python, sql, database

I'm not sure why I get this error when I test this function. Can anyone please help me fix this?

```
cur.execute(q, args)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "FROM": syntax error
```

This is my desired output:

```
print(get_course_time(db, "MGEB02H3F"))

# [('MGEB02H3F', '214', '17-12-14', '14:00'), ('MGEB02H3F', '215', '17-12-14', '14:00'), 
#  ('MGEB02H3F', '216', '17-12-14', '14:00'), ('MGEB02H3F', '217', '17-12-14', '14:00'), 
#  ('MGEB02H3F', '218', '17-12-14', '14:00')]
```

And current code:

```
def get_course_time(db, course):
"""Return the course number, ID, the date and start time of the given 
   course's exam for all sections. Note there are only multiple sections 
   if the course IDs are different."""

return run_query(db, '''SELECT Courses.Course FROM Courses 
                        JOIN Time on Time.Course, ID, Date, Start 
                        FROM Time  WHERE course = ?''', (course,))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a second `FROM` at the end of your `JOIN` clause. Also, the `JOIN` clause seems wrong, but the error you see is because of the second `FROM`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it works...

```
return run_query(db, ''' SELECT Courses.Course, Courses.ID, Time.Date, Time.Start
FROM Courses JOIN Time ON Courses.ID = Time.ID WHERE Course = ? ''', [course])


get_course_time(db, 'ACTB40H3F')
```

[('ACTB40H3F', '1', '17-12-12', '14:00')]

You have to remember in python, there are certain ways you need to perform, in order to add extra parameters for the code to work. Enjoy!

Comment: I'm talking about the function right before get_course_time_section.

Comment: I made my edit, it is because of your bracket, make it square brackets

Comment: @bigD also you need to connect the ID from Courses and Time, for the values to match

Comment: In both functions?

Comment: Yes, because the two different tables have something in common which is their ID. Without their ID, how can you match the Courses and their respective time?

Comment: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Courses.Course I get this error now

Comment: Lol nvm I accidentally did lower case c

Comment: Lol I tried doing get_locations first cuz it looks similar to get_course_time

Comment: Do we need to use count for the multi_instructor function?